# GSM Modem USSD Check Balance Getting CME Error 100

Tags: c#, serial-port, gsm, at-command, ussd

I'm trying to check the SIM Card Balance via USSD using Huawei E1550 3G modem

But when i always send

```
   AT+CUSD=1,"*100#",15
```

I Get

```
   +CME Error: 100
```

And yes my modem support USSD because i have a dashboard application for the modem and i can check the balance and also recharge the SIM Card.

I'm using GSMComm library in C# i've also tried it in putty termainl but keep getting the same error

I searched for the error 100 and found that it's "Unknown Error" no really helpful :)

I did also tried changing text mode to  pdu mode before sending but nothing changed

```
   AT+CMGF=0
```

Note:
I've also tried

```
  AT+CUSD=1,"*100#"
```

the same error

and the response of

```
   AT+CUSD=?
```

is

```
  (0-2)
```

**UPDATE**

I've Converted the request "*100#" to 7bit "2A31303023" like this

```
 AT+CUSD=1,"2A31303023" ,15
```

response

```
 +CUSD: 2
```

I believe that the problem is about to be solved but what the response mean ?

Comment: What do you get in response to AT+CUSD=?  Are you sure that the USSD code *100# is supported by your operator?

Comment: Have you tried AT+CUSD=1,"*100#" i.e. without setting the 3rd parameter to 15?  Also, I assume the SIM is unlocked.

Comment: @SList the response of AT+CUSD=? is (0-2) and yes a tried at+cusd  without the third parameter and i'm sure that the code is supported

Comment: @SList but what do you mean that the SIM is unlocked ?? but i tried other commands like sending SMS and everything works find

Comment: I meant, that you have entered the PIN and unlocked the SIM.  Just trying to eliminate obvious causes! It's hard to deduce people's level of expertise from a question on SO.  Not all mobile operators use the same USSD string for retrieving the balance, you do know that don't you?  For example, in Germany, Telekom, Vodafone and E Plus use *100#, but O2 uses another string.  These points are annoying if you know them already, but your AT command is correct, and should work, so it could be some really small thing that is stopping it from working.

Comment: The next thing to try, would be another USSD string. Do you have another USSD string, and does it work with AT+CUSD?

Comment: That response means "USSD terminated by network".  But normally you would see it after you have got the update.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41643/discussion-between-codinginsane-and-s-list)

Comment: Sorry to disappear.  I can't do chat.  Have you solved it?

Comment: I know this post is ancient, put how exactly do I convert from *100# to 2A31303023, struggling to get these converters to work.

Comment: @liamod https://www.codesegment.com/GSM-alphabet.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to encode the message to [PDU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_data_unit) format

gsmcomm PDUConverter can be used to do this

https://github.com/welly87/GSMComm/blob/master/PDUConverter/GsmComm.PduConverter/SmsPdu.cs

Comment: Please show an example, because I'm unfamiliar with PDU or how to even run that c# code (there's no main, and lots of unknowns)

Comment: @MarkJeronimus https://www.codesegment.com/GSM-alphabet.htm

Answer (score 2):

I solve this problem by using `ATZ` it's like this

```
AT+CMGF=1
ATZ
At+CUSD=1,"*100#",15
```

And it works great

Comment: ATZ resets to default