# How to send ctrl+z to serial port using c#

Tags: c#, serial-port, gsm

I have tried the following:
(This "whatever" is a 4 digit pin asked to enter after sending a AT+STGR=3,1 to the port)

```
1. this.port.WriteLine("whatever\0x1A");

2. this.port.WriteLine("whatever"+ char.ConvertFromUtf32(26));

3. this.port.WriteLine("whatever\u0001");

4. this.port.WriteLine("whatever"+(char)26);

5. this.port.WriteLine("whatever");
   SendKeys.Send("^(z)");

6. this.port.WriteLine("whatever");
   this.port.Write(new byte[] { 0x1A }, 0, 1);

7. this.port.WriteLine("whatever");
   this.port.Write(new byte[] { 0x26}, 0, 1);
```

None of them works, but when using putty and entering the code followed by ctrl+z key everything works perfectly, so can anyone tell me exactly how does putty sends this ctrl+z to the serial port? Or if possible give a solution to this problem in c#?
The reply back from the modem every time I try the c# codes given above is:

```
+CME ERROR: 100
```

Serial Port Initialization:

```
            port.PortName = "COM3";
            port.BaudRate = 115200;
            port.DataBits = 8;
            port.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            port.Parity = Parity.None;
            port.ReadTimeout = 300;
            port.WriteTimeout = 300;
            port.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
            port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(this.port_DataReceived);
            port.Open();
            port.DtrEnable = true;
            port.RtsEnable = true;
```

Comment: read the response / answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862684/sending-ctrlc-over-serial-port-in-c

Comment: @MethodMan I have tried (char)26 which is supposed to send the ascii equivalent of sending a ctrl+z. But as I mentioned it didnt work out. Or do you think this is not the way to send it? If so, could you please write the proper way of sending it?

Comment: Use Write Byte 0x26.

Comment: @jdweng could you please kindly write the code in as an answer?

Comment: try this :          this.port.Write(new byte[] { 0x1A }, 0, 1);

Comment: @jdweng tried, but no luck :(

Comment: @jdweng please check number 6 and 7 if that is the way you meant if to be written.

Comment: Make sure the port is set to 8 bit no parity. this.port = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort("Com1", 9600, System.IO.Ports.Parity.None, 8, System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One);
            this.port.Handshake = System.IO.Ports.Handshake.None;

Comment: Since Putty works for you, are you positive that the port settings in Putty are also used in your program?  @jdweng -- ASCII codes do not require 8-bit char frames.

Comment: @jdweng it was set exactly like how you said.

Comment: @sawdust, ya I am positive about that.

Comment: It seems there is something different in your serial port configuration. Post the code you're using to initialize and configure your serial port. Otherwise there's nothing we can do to help.

Comment: Also, what does "it doesn't work" mean? Are the other characters written, but not the Ctrl+Z? Is something other than Ctrl+Z received in its place? When you do `this.port.WriteLine("whatever\0x1a");`, what is received on the other end?

Comment: @JimMischel I have added the port config in the question, and yes the "whatever" part do get passed to the serial port perfectly, it is only the ctrl+z which is making the problem.

Comment: @MachineLearning, if this was a duplicate then I wouldn't have even posted it as not working. If a space is given between then wouldn't it take that space as a part of that "whatever"?

Comment: @JimMischel, this is what replied back from the modem "+CME ERROR: 100"

Comment: Is this of any help to you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20111517/gsm-modem-ussd-check-balance-getting-cme-error-100

Comment: @JimMischel, thanks, but unfortunately its not related, I am using stk and at a point I am supposed to enter a pin, I had used ussd like shown there but ussd codes ran perfectly. So, my best guess is that the \0x1A is also being taken as a part of the pin string instead as a hex for ctrl+Z.

Comment: Try "whatever\u001A" or "whatever" sleep(200) "\u001A"

Comment: What verification method are you using?  Maybe the code is being sent but your verification method isn't returning accurate results.

Answer (score 0):

Try `"whatever\u001A"` or `"whatever"` `Sleep` `"\u001A"`.

Also check the **whole** sequence of commands/responses you're sending/receiving through the connection.

This is an example, to be adapted to your specific case.

```
//TODO initialize the serialConnection and open it
//TODO specific commands...
serialConnection.WriteLine("AT+CPIN=\"1234\""); // replace according to your real situation
var response = serialConnection.ReadExisting();
Console.WriteLine("pin resp: " + response);
Thread.Sleep(200);
//TODO other specific commands?
serialConnection.Write("whatever");
//Thread.Sleep(200); uncomment this if it helps
serialConnection.Write(new byte[]{26}, 0, 1); // or Write("\u001A")
response = serialConnection.ReadExisting();
Console.WriteLine("ctrl-z resp: {0}", response);
//closing stuff, etc...
```

Comment: problem is this modem don't hold input buffers. So, there is no way to confirm exactly how the inputs are received by the modem. It works up to the point where I send AT+STGR=3,1 to get the ">" where I am supposed to enter the pin and press ctrl+z to confirm. I will try by adding a thread sleep between the pin and the ctrl+Z and let you know. But, I hardly think that will solve anything.

Comment: Here I'm also suggesting to enter return (WriteLine) after the pin (then sleep and Ctrl+z)

Comment: you may need a return `\r` also after the `AT+STGR=3,1` and before the pin

Answer (score 0):

Find a ASCII map like [this](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/c0.html) for the ctrl codes.  Looks like for ctrl Z you need an ASCII 0x26.  I would define it something like

```
char CtrlZ = (char)26;
char CR = (char)13;

serialport1.WriteLine(string.Format("whatever{0}{1}",CtrlZ, CR));
```

Comment: I faced similar issues, this solution solved my problem. This should be set as correct answer.

Comment: The link is dead. :(

Comment: Just google "ASCII Map" and go to images, you'll find a bunch.